# Payment Later/Payment Method missing

Tags: civievent, payment-processor

I was hoping someone could help me with this. I've been working on this for a couple of days and can't figure this out.

Basically, the payment method block is missing from Event online registration pages.  When I fill in payment information and submit, I get the the following message.

> Please correct the following errors in the form fields below:
>
> ```
> Please select a Payment Method
> ```

The problem is there is no Payment Method block including the Pay Later in the Registration page even though the option is selected in the configuration.

There is no error in the Civicrm log. (ConfigAndLog)
And couldn't find anything applicable in /var/log/apache2/error.log.
Same for the Drupal Log.

Also, it does not appear to be a CSS issue as the block is just missing on the registration page according to firebug.

I did find this, but it didn't help much.
https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=35391.0

Any ideas?

I'm running Drupal 6.37 and CiviCRM 4.6.8. (I know. I know.  I need to upgrade to 7, but I've consistently run into upgrade issues with my custom theme and need to get them worked out)

Apparently we didn't have any paid events over the summer so the last one was in May 2015.  So it could have stopped working anywhere between then and now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks.  It was some leftover custom code that was blocking it.  Sometimes it helps to write things out!